# Compare 2 files line by line, ignoring the last word when comparing, and extract lines only found in primary file

Tags: bash, shell

In a shell script, I'm trying to compare two files line-by-line, ignoring the last word in each line.

If a line exists in file A but not in B, I want to add the whole line from file A to the end of file B.

So far, it will output what I want, but does not include the last word in the matched line.

**Current Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

rev settings.py | cut -d' ' -f2- | rev > settings.tmp
rev settings_template.py | cut -d' ' -f2- | rev > settings_template.tmp

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}(!($0 in a)){print}' settings.tmp settings_template.tmp > diffs.tmp
 if [ -f "diffs.tmp" ]
 then
     printf "\n" >> settings.py
     cat diffs.tmp >> settings.py
fi

rm *.tmp
```

**settings.py (pre-script execution):**

```
# Comment about hosts
HOSTS = 1

# Debug settings - only enable True for debugging issues
# Default = False
DEBUG = False
```

**settings_template.py:**

```
# Comment about hosts
HOSTS = 1

# Debug settings - only enable True for debugging issues
# Default = False
DEBUG = False

# Enable auto-checking for an update
# If set to True, xyz
# Default = True
CHECK_FOR_UDPATES = True
```

**settings.py (post script execution):**

```
# Comment about hosts
HOSTS = 1

# Debug settings - only enable True for debugging issues
# Default = False
DEBUG = False

# Enable auto-checking for an
# If set to True,
# Default =
CHECK_FOR_UDPATES =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go `awk`, you can forget about `rev`, `cut` and the like. A result functionally identical to your expected output can be achieved with a one-liner:

```
awk '{b=$0;$NF=""}!($0 in a){print b}NR==FNR{a[$0]}' \
        settings.py settings_template.py >settings.py.new
mv settings.py.new settings.py
```

The trick is that `$NF=""` deletes the last word of a line (which I had already saved in `b`), and cripples `$0`, which can then be used for comparison.

**settings.py.new**

```
# Comment about hosts
HOSTS = 1

# Debug settings - only enable True for debugging issues
# Default = False
DEBUG = False
# Enable auto-checking for an update
# If set to True, xyz
CHECK_FOR_UDPATES = True
```

The problem is that in this way, all empty lines after the first are not printed, because an empty line is already registered in `a`. If this is not acceptable, just add the rule `!$0{print}` somewhere to print all empty lines from both files. Also, `# Default = False` is not repeated, and it shouldn’t be, according to your specs.

The whole concept is not very robust. What if you have lines with a one-word comment in both files? The second would be skipped, even if it was different...

YMMV, but I’d keep all empty lines and comments from the first file and print only nonempty noncomment lines from the second, this way:

```
awk '{b=$0;$NF=""}NR==FNR{a[$0];print b;next}/^#/||!$0{next}!($0 in a){print b}' \
        settings.py settings_template.py > settings.py.new
```

In this case,

**settings.py.new**

```
# Comment about hosts
HOSTS = 1

# Debug settings - only enable True for debugging issues
# Default = False
DEBUG = False
CHECK_FOR_UDPATES = True
```

I hope I have shown enough awk code to help you get the exact result you want.

If something is not clear, ask, and I’ll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!  I can't believe this was all done in one line.  I understand the concern on duplicate or one word comments.  I'll have to work around that.